# Get Child TD by Class based on Table with ID

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with an id of `'sCompSumm'` I would like to get hold of the `TD` with a class of `'VIEWBOXCAPTION'` and set its `height` to be `118px`.

How would I achieve this in jQuery?

Table

```
<table width="100%" height="118" id="sCompSumm" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD colSpan=10></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR></TR>
        <TR>
            <TD vAlign=top>
                <SPAN id=_Captcomp_name class=VIEWBOXCAPTION>Company Name:</SPAN>
                <BR><SPAN id=_Datacomp_name class=VIEWBOX>Access UK Ltd (Harpenden)</SPAN>
            </TD>
            <INPUT name=_HIDDENcomp_name value="Access UK Ltd (Harpenden)" type=hidden>
            <TD vAlign=top> 
                <SPAN id=_Captcomp_website class=VIEWBOXCAPTION>Website:</SPAN>
                <BR>
                <SPAN id=_Datacomp_website class=VIEWBOX>
                    <A class=WEBLINK href="http://www.theaccessgroup.com" target=EWAREVISITS>http://www.theaccessgroup.com</A>&nbsp;
                </SPAN>
            </TD>
            <INPUT name=_HIDDENcomp_website value=www.theaccessgroup.com type=hidden>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD vAlign=top>
                <SPAN id=_Captcomp_c_registration class=VIEWBOXCAPTION>Company Registration:</SPAN>
                <BR>
                <SPAN style="WIDTH: 100px" id=_Datacomp_c_registration class=VIEWBOX>&nbsp;</SPAN>
            </TD>
            <INPUT name=_HIDDENcomp_c_registration type=hidden>
            <TD vAlign=top>
                <SPAN id=_Captcomp_sector class=VIEWBOXCAPTION>Industry Type:</SPAN>
                <BR>
                <SPAN id=_Datacomp_sector class=VIEWBOX>&nbsp;</SPAN>
                </TD>
            <INPUT name=_HIDDENcomp_sector type=hidden>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD vAlign=top>
                <SPAN id=_Captcomp_employees class=VIEWBOXCAPTION>Employees:</SPAN>
                <BR>
                <SPAN style="WIDTH: 100px" id=_Datacomp_employees class=VIEWBOX>&nbsp;</SPAN>
            </TD>
            <INPUT name=_HIDDENcomp_employees type=hidden>
            <TD vAlign=top>
                <SPAN id=_Captcomp_secterr class=VIEWBOXCAPTION>Territory:</SPAN>
                <BR>
                <SPAN id=_Datacomp_secterr class=VIEWBOX>Worldwide&nbsp;</SPAN>
            </TD>
            <INPUT name=_HIDDENcomp_secterr value=-2147483640 type=hidden>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried to learn the basics of jQuery on your own? I see that you've asked a number of [jQuery questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:557176+[jquery]), so it surprises me that you don't know how to do this most basic task.

Comment: ...and your code shows `VIEWBOXCAPTION` on a nested `span`, but your question asks for the `td` with that class.

Comment: Also, your markup is invalid. You can't have an `<input>` as a child of a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
$("#sCompSumm").find('span.VIEWBOXCAPTION').parent().css("height","118px");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#sCompSumm .VIEWBOXCAPTION").closest("td").height(118);
```

This will find all elements with `class="VIEWBOXCAPTION"` elements in the object with `id="#sCompSumm"`, then for each one, it will find the parent `td` element and set its height to 118px.

**Note  1:** Because there are no TD elements that actually have a `class="VIEWBOXCAPTION"`, this code finds the TD elements that contain an object with that class which is not exactly what you asked, but what it appears you must have meant.

**Note 2:** Your HTML should probably adopt the safer practice of quoting around attributes like this:

```
<TD vAlign="top"><SPAN id="_Captcomp_name" class="VIEWBOXCAPTION">Company Name:</SPAN>
```

Comment: Quoting around attribute values is not required given OP's attribute values. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted

Comment: @amnotiam - I changed my answer to suggest the use of "safer" practice of quoting for attributes.  That way there is no risk of accidentally running into a character that isn't allowed without quoting.  I didn't mean to imply it was required, just that it was a better practice.  There's a reason why most websites use quoting on attributes.

Comment: Now I can +1 you. :) I tend to think *(or assume)* that the reason quotes are so widely used is because of XHTML. But I'll accept that it could be considered safer to include them as a habit.

Comment: @amnotiam - This is my personal opinion, but I find HTML with quote attributes a LOT easier to read and scan while looking for something in particular.  it could be that my eyes are just trained for that pattern or it could be that it's just easier to see the delineation between attribute name and value when the value is quoted.  In places like the starting value for an input field that has spaces or other special characters in it, it is required too so I think it's a good practice.  Thanks for the +1.

Comment: Yeah, and I totally respect that. My opinion is that it's cleaner and more readable without the quotes, but I could see how other would want them there. And you're right about leading (or any) spaces. Those situations will make them mandatory.

Comment: @amnotiam - Yeah, I guess it's just a personal opinion/preference thing.